# how to avoid using absolute url in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js, absolute-path

i work on a mobile application that uses phonegap and jquery in client side , and a rest Api in server side,
i use usually calls to absolute url(to the server) to get json data with : $.getjson(url,function) and i use the absolute url, what i want is to avoid using absolute url and use relative one like in MVC architecture ,i tried base tag but i have a "Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers" error and relative urls does't work, so i walked throught javascript router like backbone.js but it doesn't seem to solve my issue.
can you help?

Comment: Can you post the complete URLs you're trying to deal with? Your issue doesn't seem related to absolute VS relative URLs but to some server configuration (_"Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"_).

Comment: with absolute path all works good, but it's recommanded to me to work without absolute url and configure my application to redirect or root relative urls to the apporopriate absolute urls, this is the compete url i try to deal $.getjson(" http://externaldomain.com/repositories?format=json ", function)

Comment: External URLS always need absolute paths.

Comment: i thought to built a smal reverse proxy to root relative path to the appropirate absolute one but i don't know if it's a good solutionand how to begin